# laravel ck-editor is not loading in browser

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

laravel-ckeditor is not loading in browser, I followed the installation process as described here https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor#publish-the-resources

Also when I open view source in browser and goto the link, it says Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

I have already added registered it to Application Service Providers located in `config/app.php` as:
`Unisharp\Ckeditor\ServiceProvider::class`

ran command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ckeditor
```

without error

and I have initiated ckeditor by jquery selector as:

```
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $('textarea').ckeditor();
    // $('.textarea').ckeditor(); // if class is prefered.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best suggestion use cdns [link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ckeditor)

or download put in **public** folder and you should include [Jquery](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery) before ckeditor link

or you try this also

```
<script src="{{base_path().('/vendor/theseer/build.xml')}}"></script>
```

Comment: i will try that